# Azure Stream Analytics Job hangs or not processing input

Tags: azure-stream-analytics

Using Azure stream analytics job with input - IoT Hub, output - Azure Document DB and Azure Event Hub.
Streaming Unit assigned - 1.
Message rate - 36 messages per seconds, message payload less than 1 KB.

after some time ASA job stop processing input messages as on Monitoring graph it shows zero input and didn't output any event. Verified messages coming to IoT Hub.

No error log in Activity and Diagnostic log for that duration.

On restart without any modification it start working as expected. Showing input count on ASA job monitoring graph and generate output event.

It occurs continuously on random time interval.

Comment: I encountered a similar problem when I was receiving data from EventHub and using $Default consumer group, same time another application also using $Default consumer group. so I was partial message